# Compiler Error RxSwift: Use of unresolved identifier 'Materialize'

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, rx-swift

I added RxSwift library to my project.But when i tried to run the app then i always got compiler error like **Use of unresolved identifier 'Materialize'**.This error occurs in the  **Observable+Single.swift** class.The error occurs method mentioned below.Please help me how to solve this issue.

```
extension ObservableType {
     public func materialize() -> Observable<Event<E>> {
        return Materialize(source: self.asObservable())
    }
}

extension ObservableType where E: EventConvertible {
       public func dematerialize() -> Observable<E.ElementType> {
        return Dematerialize(source: self.asObservable())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `Materialize` class is not publicly available. Try using a lower-case "m".

```
extension ObservableType {

    /**
     Convert any Observable into an Observable of its events.
     - seealso: [materialize operator on reactivex.io](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/materialize-dematerialize.html)
     - returns: An observable sequence that wraps events in an Event<E>. The returned Observable never errors, but it does complete after observing all of the events of the underlying Observable.
     */
    public func materialize() -> Observable<Event<E>>
}
```

Comment: I already tried with lower-case "m".But then i got another error like "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments".